# What is $H^{p, q}_D(K)$, for a double complex $K$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading Bott-Tu and on the top of page 167, there is the symbol

$$H^{p, q}_D \{ C^*( \mathcal U, \Omega^*) \}$$

What is does this symbol mean?

Here is the setup. Let $K = \bigoplus K^{p, q}$ be a double complex with vertical differential $d$ and horizontal differential $\delta$. From the double complex $K$, we can form the single complex by setting $K_n := \bigoplus_{p+q=n} K^{p, q}$, with differential $D:= \delta + (-1)^p d$. In particular, $C^p(\mathcal U, \Omega^q)$, which is equal to $q$-forms on $p+1$-fold intersections of open sets in $\mathcal U$, is indeed a double complex. The symbol $H^{n}_D \{ C^*( \mathcal U, \Omega^*) \}$ makes sense to me.

Thank you.

Comment: From a double complex you can construct a "single" complex. That symbol you ask about is the cohomology of that.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez The cohomology of the single complex (at the $n$th place) is $H^n_D(K)$. Is it true that $H^n_D = \bigoplus_{p+q=n} H^{pq}$? Is $H^{pq}_D$ equal to the set of elements $K^{pq}$ that are $D$-closed, modulo the image of $D: K_{n-1} \to K_n$ intersect $K^{pq}$? Thank you.

Comment: No, that is not true.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez In that case, I am still confused what $H^{pq}_D$ is. I understand the cohomology of the single complex associated to $K$ (namely, the kernel of $K_n \to K_{n+1}$ mod the image of $K_{n-1} \to K_n$, where $K_n = \bigoplus_{p+q=n} K^{pq}$, and the maps are given by $D$ as described above.